# While returing values from form i get Bad Request The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand

Tags: html, python-3.x, forms, flask

I created an HTML form with multiple fields
and i rendered the contact form using flask
when i try to return any one value it works perfectly fine,
but when i want to return multiple values it returned this error message

Bad Request The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand

```
<form name="info-form" method="POST" action="#">
<div class="general-info">
        <div class="row-1">
          <input type="text" placeholder="First name" name="fname" required />
          <input type="text" placeholder="Middle name" name="mname" />
          <input type="text" placeholder="Last name" name="lname" required />
          <br />
        </div>

        <div class="row-2">
          <input
            type="text"
            placeholder="Father's name"
            name="father-name"
            required
          />
          <label for="gender">Gender</label>
          <select name="gender" required>
            <option value="">None</option>
            <option value="Male">Male</option>
            <option value="Female">Female</option>
          </select>
          <input
            type="text"
            placeholder="Contact number"
            name="contact"
            required
          />
          <label>Enter birth date:</label>
          <input
            type="date"
            id="birthday"
            name="birthday"
            name="dob"
            required
          /><br />
        </div>

        <div class="row-3">
          <input type="text" placeholder="Aadhar no" name="aadhar" required />
          <input
            type="text"
            placeholder="Address Line 1"
            name="address1"
            required
          />
          <input
            type="text"
            placeholder="Address Line 2"
            name="address2"
            required
          /><br />
        </div>
      </div>
  <input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form
```

I'm getting values like this:

```
@app.route('/', methods=['POST'])
def get_values():
    first_name = request.form['fname']
    return first_name
```

Though we can return or yield multiple values in python but i preferred returning dictionary or list of values
And i get this error when i return multiple values from the form
For any one value it works fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To all those who are facing the same problem, cross verify your input fields name and that you are using in py file.

Also you can't return a list, return a dictionary or tuple instead